# Intermittent content type of the binding failure

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, character-encoding, wcf-binding

I am sending same request to a web service several times by using WCF and some of my reqests are failing with following error message.

```
The content type text/xml;UTF-8; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly
```

When I check the raw messages of successful and failed attemps with Fiddler , I see that there is following difference.

### Successful

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 07:15:57 GMT
Server: unknown
Content-Length: 1502
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

### Failed

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2015 07:16:03 GMT
Server: unknown
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml;UTF-8; charset=UTF-8
```

Successfully observed message does not have Transfer-Encoding and text/xml;UTF-8 fields.

I am not sure those extras may cause error? What might lead such differences and  how can I overcome this problem?